# Undefined error accessing JSON data in Jquery and mapping it on a chart

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, decode

I have a **PHP** file that returns a JSON script in the format below.

```
              {"content":
                  [{
                    "si":173,
                    "qi":"1990"
                   },
                   {
                    "si":121,
                    "qi":"2001"
                   }
                  ]
               }
```

And below is my code in jquery i have written to load data from  the above php file into an array
that would later be used to map a chart.

```
$(function(){

    // data arrays
    var chartBar5Labels = [];
    var chartBar5Data   = [];

     $.ajax({
              type:'GET',
              url: './dash_x.php',
                      data:{dc:110},
              success: function (data) {
                 jQuery.each(data.content,function(i,item){
                        chartBar5Labels[i]  = item.si;     
                        chartBar5Data[i]    = item.qi; 
                }); 
                
            } 
        });   
        
   // the chart 

 var ctx3 = document.getElementById('chartBar5').getContext('2d');
        new Chart(ctx3, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: chartBar5Labels,  // ['Q4,2021', 'Q1,2022', 'Q2,2022', 'Q3,2022', 'Q4,2022'],
            datasets: [{
              data: chartBar5Data,  //[191,122,126,127,100],
              backgroundColor: ['#aa9e9e', '#f1f1f1','#f1f1f1','#f10075','#aa9e9e','#f10075']
            } ]
          },
          options: {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
              display: false,
                labels: {
                  display: false
                }
            },
            scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero:true,
                  fontSize: 11,
                }
              }],
              xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero:true,
                  fontSize: 11,
                  max: 180
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        });

    })
```

The problem with the above code is, data does not seem to reach the arrays, and when i try to test any of the arrays for presence of data.

```
                                  alert(chartBar5Labels[2]);
```

it alerts undefined. been working on this, but dont seem to find where the error is.

Comment: Assuming your code is exactly as provided - you're trying to eat your pizza before it's been delivered.  Move your `new Chart` etc code into a function and call it from the ajax `success:`.

Comment: Tangential, but in general, use plain JS when functionality overlaps (like `jQuery.each`).

Comment: Add some basic console.log() s, eg inside every `function (..) { console.log("...")` and before `new Chart` - use a different message each time (ofc) - you'll see it goes "load","chart","success"

Comment: To expand on the first comment: the XHR request finishes at an arbitrary time in the future but the rest of the code keeps executing. You shouldn't try to access the label/data arrays until the request has completed.

Comment: wow thanx guys, i did implement the  `.push()` and also add the code in the success function , it still did not work, but when i added  `dataType: 'json'`     it executed just fine. thanx guys